# JS function declaration with the limit of 1 char per line?

Tags: javascript, function

Im currently doing some JS challenge with these rules:
You need to write a function f that returns the string Hello, world!.
Requirement: Every line must have at most 1 character, and total number of lines must be less than 145
I've done that, but only thing that i struggle with is function declaration.
Shortest i was come up with is:

```
f
=
_=>
```

There must be some 'hack' way to declare a function in js with limit of 1 char per line.

Comment: Limit of 1 char per line in code.

Comment: [Related kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/59a421985eb5d4bb41000031), not sure if you got it from some other source, there are many.

Comment: If it is a challenge, shouldn't you do it yourself?

Comment: i dont asking for direct solution, just a hint will do

Comment: I think you should use this: https://github.com/aemkei/jsfuck

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into an array using: `var charArray=str.split("")`.

And then do something with this, maybe `forEach()`.

Comment: 1 char per line. `var charArray=str.split("")` is 27 chars.

Comment: @Whatever No, try to throw to console or as code that:`var a='hghljbuygc';` and than `console.log(a.split(""));`. every char should be single item.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid keywords, they won't work. Apart from that, there are a couple things you should know:

- Don't use strings, there is no way to make them multiline. Template literals <s>won't work either because of newline chars</s> will work if used correctly.
- `Function` allows you to build a function from a string, e.g. `Function("return 'Hello, world!'")` will generate a function that returns `Hello, world!`, though there are other (and possibly shorter) ways to create a function returning string.
- [JSF](http://www.jsfuck.com/) and destructuring assignment (I'll leave this one as a mysterious hint because after all it is a challenge and you are the one supposed to figure it all out!).

Comment: Template literals followed by removing the newlines might work, but it would depend on the string for whether that's shorter than doing it character by character

Comment: @Bergi, nope. Code generated by JSF is likely to be longer than 1000 lines because it uses only 6 chars. We can use all ASCII. I don't want to say too much because I don't want to give away the way to solve this challenge. Template literals might work, but additional function calls are needed, which might make the code longer.

Comment: JSF worked for me i figured it out by myself, but thx for the answer, this challenge can be done with 99 lines only. And you can do this with string templates actually, but it will be longer, e.g. `  H  `  [  1  ]  +  `  e  `  [  1  ] etc.(every char on the new line ofc)